# Hadoop 2: Empty result when using custom InputFormat

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop2, recordreader

I want to use a own `FileInputFormat` with a custom `RecordReader` to read csv data into `<Long><String>` pairs.

Therefore I created the class `MyTextInputFormat`:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileSplit;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InputSplit;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.RecordReader;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reporter;

public class MyTextInputFormat extends FileInputFormat<Long, String> {

  @Override
  public RecordReader<Long, String> getRecordReader(InputSplit input, JobConf job, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
      reporter.setStatus(input.toString());
      return new MyStringRecordReader(job, (FileSplit)input);
  }

  @Override
  protected boolean isSplitable(FileSystem fs, Path filename) {
    return super.isSplitable(fs, filename);
  }
}
```

and the class `MyStringRecordReader`:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileSplit;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LineRecordReader;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.RecordReader;

public class MyStringRecordReader implements RecordReader<Long, String> {

    private LineRecordReader lineReader;
    private LongWritable lineKey;
    private Text lineValue;

    public MyStringRecordReader(JobConf job, FileSplit split) throws IOException {
        lineReader = new LineRecordReader(job, split);

        lineKey = lineReader.createKey();
        lineValue = lineReader.createValue();

        System.out.println("constructor called");
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        lineReader.close();
    }

    @Override
    public Long createKey() {
        return lineKey.get();
    }

    @Override
    public String createValue() {
        System.out.println("createValue called");
        return lineValue.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public long getPos() throws IOException {
        return lineReader.getPos();
    }

    @Override
    public float getProgress() throws IOException {
        return lineReader.getProgress();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean next(Long key, String value) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("next called");

        // get the next line
        if (!lineReader.next(lineKey, lineValue)) {
            return false;
        }

        key = lineKey.get();
        value = lineValue.toString();

        System.out.println(key);
        System.out.println(value);


        return true;
    }
}
```

In my Spark application I read the file by calling `sparkContext.hadoopFile` method. But I only **get an empty output** from the following code:

```
public class AssociationRulesAnalysis {

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JavaRDD<String> inputRdd = sc.hadoopFile(inputFilePath, MyTextInputFormat.class, Long.class, String.class).map(new Function<Tuple2<Long,String>, String>() {
            @Override
            public String call(Tuple2<Long, String> arg0) throws Exception {
                System.out.println("map: " + arg0._2());
                return arg0._2();
            }
        });

        List<String> asList = inputRdd.take(10);
        for(String s : asList) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
}
```

I only get 10 empty lines back from the RDD.

The console output with the added `prints` looks the following:

```
=== APP STARTED : local-1467182320798
constructor called
createValue called
next called
0
ä1
map:
next called
8
ö2
map:
next called
13
ü3
map:
next called
18
ß4
map:
next called
23
ä5
map:
next called
28
ö6
map:
next called
33
ü7
map:
next called
38
ß8
map:
next called
43
ä9
map:
next called
48
ü10
map:
next called
54
ä11
map:
next called
60
ß12
map:
next called
12
=====================
constructor called
createValue called
next called
0
ä1
map:
next called
8
ö2
map:
next called
13
ü3
map:
next called
18
ß4
map:
next called
23
ä5
map:
next called
28
ö6
map:
next called
33
ü7
map:
next called
38
ß8
map:
next called
43
ä9
map:
next called
48
ü10
map:










Stopping...
```

(The RDD data is printed below the `=====` output (10 empty lines!!!). The output above the `=====` seems to be made by the `RDD.count` call. In the `next` method the correct keys & values are shown!? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`lineKey` and `lineValue` are never initialized to the `key` and `value` passed in to the overriden `next` method in your `MyStringRecordReader`. Hence it is always showing the EMPTY string when you try to use your `RecordReader`.
If you want a different key and value for a record in the file then you need to use key and value passed in to the `next` method and initialize them with your computed key and value. If you do not intend to change the key/value record then get rid of the following. Everytime you execute this piece of code you are overwriting key/value read from file with your EMPTY string and 0L.

```
key = lineKey.get();
value = lineValue.toString();
```

Comment: I changed the contents of the "createKey" and "createValue" methods to the lines above "key = lineKey.get()" and "value = lineValue.toString()" without success, unfortunately still getting 10 empty lines.

Comment: Changed this also in my code snippet in the question above

Comment: createKey and createValue are used to create appropriate key and value object. These API will not assign the data values from the file to key and value. This is the responsibility of "next" implementation. Your "next" implementation is overwriting the key and value. Try printing out the key and value in next method to see what I mean to say.

Comment: I added some prints to the next method, and I see, that the "key" and "value" are filled correctly, but I don't get how to adapt the "createValue" and "createKey" methods. Or do I have to adapt my "next" method? However I don't get it... Can you please give a coding example?

Comment: glad that I could answer your question "I only get 10 empty lines shown in my console! Can someone help?". Now coming back your other question about coding example, I did not understand what you are trying to do by writing your own RecordReader.

Comment: Ah ok - I want to write my own RecordReader because I need to read a CSV file with another encoding (not the Text.class stanard utf-8)! So I want to use a custom Reader which works with Strings & the correct encoding.

Comment: From the output you posted above, I think you are able to read what you want. Isn't it ? Moreover the LineRecordReader. lineKey and lineValue, none of this is taking part in reading your file.

Comment: Hey, if you think I have answered your question about EMPTY values, could you please accept the answer ?

Comment: The problem is also that my MyTextInputFormat won't give back anything to the RDD. There I've got only empty rows and I don't why!

Comment: I thought you understood why you are getting EMPTY rows in all of this discussion. Your next question was about reading data in different encoding other than UTF-8. Isn't it ?